# Jenkins failing gradle test task, can't find import files

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using Jenkins to run gradlew as a build step.  `build.gradle` has a test task in it.  When the test task runs, it fails because the Groovy file it's trying to compile has 5 `import` statements at the top.  These classes are ones I created in a sub-folder.  However, when I use the Job DSL plugin to create Jenkins Jobs using the same Groovy files, it runs just fine.  Following is the error I see:

```
09:32:31.930 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] debug.JobScriptsSpec > test script JenkinsJobs.groovy FAILED
09:32:31.930 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     Expected no exception to be thrown, but got 'javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslException'
09:32:31.930 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at spock.lang.Specification.noExceptionThrown(Specification.java:118)
09:32:31.930 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         at debug.JobScriptsSpec.test script #file.name(JobScriptsSpec.groovy:31)
09:32:31.930 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger] 
09:32:31.930 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         Caused by:
09:32:31.930 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslException: startup failed:
09:32:31.945 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]         script: 1: unable to resolve class utilities.GitConfiguration
09:32:31.945 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]          @ line 1, column 1.
09:32:31.945 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]            import utilities.GitConfiguration
09:32:31.945 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]
```

I am emulating what is being done here: https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example Take note of the "Testing" section.

I have tried adding to the classpath doing the following but I still get the same error:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files('/jobs/utilities')
    }
}
```

My basic file structure is this:

```
jenkins-jobs
  |-build.gradle
  |-jobs
     |-JenkinsJobs.groovy
         |-utilities
             |-GitConfiguration.groovy
             |-other groovy files I try to import
```

In a nutshell, the question I'm trying to ask is how do I make Gradle happy while trying to include user created imports in my Groovy files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `jobs/utilities` put those sources under `buildSrc/src/main/groovy`

This is a place for your custom build sources that Gradle will build automatically and it will be available in your build scripts. It is well described in user guide here -https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would suggest starting by `git clone` [job-dsl-gradle-example](https://github.com/sheehan/job-dsl-gradle-example/) and then work from there.